# NPM Error: Cannot find module 'node-bin-darwin-arm64/package.json' fixes on the internet not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I tried node V16 and V17 from the website, from n and from nvm with arch. I deleted the node_modules folder, but nothing.
I'm using a M1 macbook pro
Error when running npm i:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/redacted/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Software/Code/Discord-Bots/DijkendamDiscordBot/node_modules/node
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node installArchSpecificPackage
npm ERR! npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for node-darwin-arm64@16.13.2.
npm ERR! npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! npm ERR!     /Users/redacted/.npm/_logs/2022-02-11T23_06_22_932Z-debug-0.log
npm ERR! node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
npm ERR!   throw err;
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Error: Cannot find module 'node-bin-darwin-arm64/package.json'
npm ERR! Require stack:
npm ERR! - /Users/redacted/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Software/Code/Discord-Bots/DijkendamDiscordBot/node_modules/node/installArchSpecificPackage.js
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
npm ERR!     at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:19)
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/redacted/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Software/Code/Discord-Bots/DijkendamDiscordBot/node_modules/node-bin-setup/index.js:19:27)
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:520:28)
npm ERR!     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
npm ERR!     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5) {
npm ERR!   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
npm ERR!   requireStack: [
npm ERR!     '/Users/redacted/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Personal/Software/Code/Discord-Bots/DijkendamDiscordBot/node_modules/node/installArchSpecificPackage.js'
npm ERR!   ]
npm ERR! }

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/redacted/.npm/_logs/2022-02-11T23_06_18_606Z-debug-0.log
```

Please help i have tried everything i could find!

Comment: There is no version for your system architecture.

Comment: These seem to be the available versions: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-darwin-arm64?activeTab=versions – v16.13.2 does not exist